# List<T> clearing in a For Loop unexpectedly

Tags: c#, list, class, foreach

This error has stumped me! Essentially, the code receives a list of objects called "Parking". I want to group `Parking` objects with similar `Title`. To do this, I have thought of creating a list within a list - the `TerminalCollection` is a list of `Parking` objects and a name for reference.

To help me with this, I've created a new - temporary - `terminal` object which is a list of `Parking` objects. Whenever I find a `Parking` object in the same category, I add it to the temporary `terminal` until I find an object which doesn't fit. When this occurs, I combine the `terminal` list with a name to create a `TerminalCollection` object. And then I start the process all over again by adding the next  batch of similar `Parking` objects to the terminal.

The issue I'm finding is that when I want to clear the `terminal` list after creating a `TerminalCollection` object which contains a copy of this list, the list is cleared from `TerminalCollection` object as well!! I have no clue why because I thought I'm creating a new list and assigning a copy of `terminal` to it? Why would the new list share the same memory as that of the original `terminal`? Is there a fundamental concept I've misunderstood? Many thanks for any help and advice to get around this issue! :)

```
private static List<TerminalCollection> Terminals(List<Parking> input)
    {
        List<TerminalCollection> Terminals = new List<TerminalCollection>();
        List<Parking> terminal = new List<Parking>();
        int current = 0;
        int currentpos = 0;
        string currentname = "";
        bool clearbuffer = false;
        foreach (Parking attempt in input)
        {
            if (clearbuffer)
            {
                terminal.Clear();
                clearbuffer = false;
            }
            if (current != 0)
            {
                int checknew = int.Parse(Regex.Match(attempt.Title, @"\d+").Value);
                if (checknew - current == 0 && Regex.Match(attempt.Title, @"\d+").Index == currentpos)
                {
                    //Matches same terminal, so slot added in temporary terminal list  
                    terminal.Add(attempt);
                    currentname = Regex.Match(attempt.Title, @"^.*?\d+").Value;
                } 
                else
                {
                    //Clears and starts again (resets current and currentpos)
                    current = checknew;
                    currentpos = Regex.Match(attempt.Title, @"\d+").Index;
                    TerminalCollection final = new TerminalCollection();
                    final.Slots = terminal;
                    final.Name = currentname;
                    //One terminal added to global collection of terminals
                    Terminals.Add(final);
                    //Temporary terminal list cleared
                    clearbuffer = true;
                }
            }
            else { 
            //Gets first integer  
            current = int.Parse(Regex.Match(attempt.Title, @"\d+").Value);
            currentpos = Regex.Match(attempt.Title, @"\d+").Index;
            terminal.Clear();
            //Adds first element to start a new terminal
            terminal.Add(attempt);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: "a TerminalCollection object which contains a copy of this list"... It doesn't contain a copy of the list. It contains a copy of a reference to the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Clear` does **not** make a new list, and neither does assignment. You only make the list once, before the loop, so *every* object will point to it.

You see this manifest as the "other" lists clearing (really they are all the same list).

You need to change to this:

```
if (clearbuffer)
{
   terminal = new List<Parking>();
   clearbuffer = false;
}
```

Now each iteration will have its *own* list object, and you won't see changes to it affecting other instances.

As a total aside, consider redesigning that loop, its *really* confusing.

Comment: Beat me to it @BradleyDotNET - ignore my comment about empty(). :)

Comment: Looks like another opportunity for someone to get a refresher on reference types. :)

Comment: Many thanks @BradleyDotNET , I guess it indeed was a failure of basic understanding! :) I'll take a look at reference types on MSDN. I am picking this all up through trying things out so I'll be sure to see if I can improve my loop! Thanks! :)